# CUDA Visual profiler over a remote X session

Tags: cuda, nvvp

I am running an Ubuntu 11.10 server, CUDA-5.0 with a GTX480 on it. I am trying to run the visual profiler remotely by using Xming and Cygwin/X on Windows 8. I can successfully run xclocks, but when I try to launch /usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin/nvvp from the putty command line, it just silently exits without any errors or warnings.

I installed the default config of Cygwin/X with xorg-server, xinit and openssh packages. Do I need any more packages?

I do not want to use the command line profiler as I need the global load/store efficiency, replay and DRAM utilization, which are much more visible in the visual profiler.

Has anyone tried this before? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried running nvvp on the remote host locally? NVVP requires GTK+ (and might need some other libraries) that may not be installed on a server system.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks a lot. Installing GTK+ and Xtst6 on both the server and Cygwin allows nvvp to launch now. Can you please post your reply separately so I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVVP requires GTK+ (and some other libraries) that may not be installed on a server system.

Answer (score 0):

It may (likely) require X extensions not available in Xming (or might need alternate configuration of Xming).  You could also try cygwin and run "real" X in rootless mode.

You can also debug the X protocol to see what it's asking for (and not getting) right before it quits.  Perhaps 3d acceleration, or some backing store setting, etc.